# Need to add 3 months to each value within a column, based on the 1st '3 Months' calculated off the Admission Date column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, dateadd

I have 14K records table as the following (example of the data related to one particular client_id = 1002):
(my date format is mm/dd/yyyy, months come first)

```
ClientsEpisodes:

      client_id      adm_date      disch_date    
          1002      3/11/2005        5/2/2005
          1002      8/30/2005       2/16/2007
          1002      3/16/2017            NULL
```

In SQL Server (T-SQL) - I need to calculate + 3 months date into the new column [3Month Date], where the 1st "+ 3 months" value will be calculated off my existing [adm_date] column. Then + 3 more months should be added to the value in [3Months Date], then the next 3 months should be added to the next value in the [3Months Date] column, and so on..., until [3MonthsDate] <= [disch_date]. When [3Months Date] is more than [disch_date] then the data shouldn't be populated. If my [disch_date] IS NULL then the condition should be
[3Months Date] <= current date (whatever it is)  from GETDATE() function.

Here is what I expect to see as a result:
(I highlighted my dates offsets with different colors, for a better view)

[image]

Below, I'll clarify with more detailed explanation, about each populated (or not populated) data set:

My first [adm_date] from ClientsEpisode table was 3/11/2005.
Adding 3 months:
3/11/2005 + 3 months = 6/11/2005 - falls AFTER the initial [disch_date] (5/2/2005)  - not populated

```
   Next [adm_date] from ClientEpisode is 8/3/2005 + 3 Months = 11/30/2005; 
        then + 3 months must be added to 11/30/2005 = 2/30/2006; 
        then 2/30/2006 + 3 months = 5/30/2006; 
        then 5/30/2006 + 3 months = 8/30/2006; 
        then 8/30/2006 + 3 months = 11/30/2006;
        then 11/30/2006 + 3 months = 3/2/2007 - falls AFTER my [disch_date] 
                                                      (2/16/2007) - not populated
```

the same algorithm for the next [adm_date] - [disch_date] sets 11/5/2007-2/7/2009 (in dark blue).

then, where [adm_date] = 3/16/17, I have [disch_date] IS NULL, so, the algorithm applies until
[3 Months Date] <= current date (10/15/2020 in this case)

Comment: So, you many end with 10 or 20 columns if your `disch_date` is several years bigger then the `amd_date`?

Comment: @gotqn  No,   If my disch_date  is several years bigger than the adm_date - I'll have 10 or 20+ records within [3 Month Date] column!  As it is in my example for the last adm_date - disch_date set:  adm_date = 3/16/2017   disch_date = Null (current)= 10/15/2020
And as you can see - there are the biggest number of records for that last dataset !!!

Comment: In the highlighted section above (lines 23-26), why was the next row not included (e.g., 11/5/2008 + 3 months = 2/5/2009, which is less than 2/7/2009). Typo, or something I missed?

Comment: @seanb  Typo, I think As long as disch_date is more - should continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recursive common expression`. Below is an example. Note, that you can change the `DATEADD` part with other (for example add 90 days if you want) - it's a matter of bussness logic.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [client_id] INT
   ,[adm_date] DATE
   ,[disch_date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([client_id], [adm_date], [disch_date])
VALUES (1002, '3/11/2005 ', '5/2/2005')
      ,(1002, '8/30/2005 ', '2/16/2007')
      ,(1002, '3/16/2017 ', NULL);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [client_id]) AS [row_id]
          ,[client_id]
          ,[adm_date]
          ,DATEADD(MONTH, 3, [adm_date]) AS [3Month Date]
          ,ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE()) AS [disch_date]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 3, [adm_date]) <= ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE()) 
),
RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [row_id]
          ,[client_id]
          ,[adm_date]
          ,[3Month Date]
          ,[disch_date]
          ,0 AS [level]
    FROM DataSource
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS.[row_id]
          ,DS.[client_id]
          ,DS.[adm_date]
          ,DATEADD(MONTH, 3, RDS.[3Month Date])
          ,DS.[disch_date]
          ,[level] + 1
    FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS
        ON RDS.[row_id] = DS.[row_id]
        AND DATEADD(MONTH, 3, RDS.[3Month Date]) < DS.[disch_date]
)
SELECT *
FROM RecursiveDataSource
ORDER BY [row_id]
        ,[level];
```

Comment: Thanks so much   Sure this one will work as same as your last help with dynamic unpivot!  I'll try tomorrow when access to my Server and will update here !!!

Comment: @gotqn Do you think we need to add the max recursion option here?

Comment: It depends on the case and the data. During the years I have no such case. I am not fan also of recursive CTEs as it can easily harm performance.

Comment: @gotqn  Yes... I am facing AWFUL performance. My table is 14 000+ records and execution time is endless...   Posted here another question, and trying to research how to optimize....

Comment: I will check after several hours - currently afk.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer, but you say in the comments for that, that you have performance problems. Try this instead - it's also a lot simpler.

A recursive CTE is really useful if the value of the next row depends on the value of the previous row.

Here, we don't need the answer to the previous row - we just add *n* x 3 months (e.g., 3 months, 6 months, 9 months) and filter the rows you want to keep.

Therefore, instead of doing a recursive CTE, just do it via set logic.

Here's some data setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #Datasource (client_id int, adm_date date, disch_date date);
INSERT INTO #Datasource (client_id, adm_date, disch_date) VALUES
(1002, '20050311', '20050502'),
(1002, '20050830', '20070216'),
(1002, '20170316', NULL),
(1002, '20071105', '20090207');
```

And here's the simple SELECT

```
WITH DataSourceMod AS
    (SELECT client_id, adm_date, disch_date, ISNULL(disch_date, getdate()) AS disc_date_mod
        FROM #Datasource
    ),
Nums_One_to_OneHundred AS 
   (SELECT a * 10 + b AS n
     FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) A(a)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) B(b)
    )
SELECT ds.client_id, ds.adm_date, ds.disch_date, DATEADD(month, 3*Nums.n, ds.adm_date) AS ThreeMonthDate
FROM  DataSourceMod ds
    CROSS JOIN Nums_One_to_OneHundred Nums
WHERE DATEADD(month, 3* Nums.n, ds.adm_date) <= ds.disc_date_mod
ORDER BY ds.client_id, ds.adm_date;
```

This works by

- Calculating the effective discharge date (the specified date, or today)
- Calculating all possible rows for up to 300 months in the future (the table One_to_OneHundred .. um.. has all the values from 1 to 100, then multiplied by 3.)
- Only taking those that fulfil the date condition

You can further optimise this if desired, by limiting the number of 3 months you need to add. Here's a rough version.

```
WITH DataSourceMod AS
    (SELECT client_id, adm_date, disch_date, ISNULL(disch_date, getdate()) AS disc_date_mod, 
            FLOOR(DATEDIFF(month, adm_date, ISNULL(disch_date, getdate())) / 3) + 1 AS nMax 
        FROM #Datasource
    ),
Nums_One_to_OneHundred AS 
   (SELECT a * 10 + b AS n
     FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) A(a)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) B(b)
    )
SELECT ds.client_id, ds.adm_date, ds.disch_date, DATEADD(month, 3*Nums.n, ds.adm_date) AS ThreeMonthDate
FROM  DataSourceMod ds
    INNER JOIN Nums_One_to_OneHundred Nums ON Nums.n <= ds.nMax
WHERE DATEADD(month, 3* Nums.n, ds.adm_date) <= ds.disc_date_mod
ORDER BY ds.client_id, ds.adm_date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as well
I'll learn and try your version and - will share how it went - later tonight...

Comment: It's the same logic (but shorter and cleaner imo) to @Gotqn's in the other post/question. I originally posted there (before he put his answer in), but I moved it here as this answer is not how to make the recursive CTE faster, it's about how to actually answer this orignal question. Note that my second approach (with the INNER JOIN) probably won't be any faster - but it's worth trying.