# Slow performance on Recursive CTE in T-SQL

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following code, (based on the community member help):

```
      use [Credible];

      WITH DataSource AS
      (
       SELECT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY epi.[client_id]) AS [row_id]
            ,epi.[client_id]
            ,CONVERT(date, epi.[admission_date]) AS [admission_date]
            ,CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, epi.[admission_date])) AS [3Month Date]
            ,CONVERT(date, ISNULL(epi.[discharge_date], GETDATE())) AS [discharge_date]

       FROM 
           [dbo].[ClientEpisode] epi

       WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 3, [admission_date]) <= ISNULL([discharge_date], GETDATE()) 
  ),
    RecursiveDataSource AS
     (
      SELECT 
            [row_id]
           ,[client_id]
           ,[admission_date]
           ,[3Month Date]
           ,[discharge_date]
           ,0 AS [level]

     FROM 
         DataSource

         UNION ALL

     SELECT 
          ds.[row_id]
         ,ds.[client_id]
         ,ds.[admission_date]
         ,DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rds.[3Month Date])
         ,ds.[discharge_date]
         ,[level] + 1

    FROM 
          RecursiveDataSource rds
          INNER JOIN DataSource ds ON 
          rds.[row_id] = ds.[row_id] AND DATEADD(MONTH, 3, rds.[3Month Date]) < ds.[discharge_date]
    )

     SELECT *

     FROM RecursiveDataSource 

     ORDER BY [row_id]
             ,[level]
     -- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

This code works with the speed around 30 sec if there are up to 1 000 records in the table.

But my table is over 14 000 records, and will grow more,
and the code works 10+++ min

Is there way to make its performance in 30 sec or so?

Thank you for help

Comment: I think I would first take the query in DataSource and split it out into a temp table and then try running the CTE against that.

Comment: I answered this here but moved the answer to the original question as it was really a response to the original question (e.g., doing the calculation a different way, rather than optimising this CTE). I've put it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383302/need-to-add-3-months-to-each-value-within-a-column-based-on-the-1st-3-months/64462525#64462525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As here you are looking for performance solution, I will advice to skip using `recursive` CTE and solve the issue in another way.

For example, a variant of this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [client_id] INT
   ,[adm_date] DATE
   ,[disch_date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([client_id], [adm_date], [disch_date])
VALUES (1002, '3/11/2005 ', '5/2/2005')
      ,(1002, '8/30/2005 ', '2/16/2007')
      ,(1002, '3/16/2017 ', NULL);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataNumers;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [client_id] INT
   ,[adm_date] DATE
   ,[disch_date] DATE
   ,[diff_in_months] INT
);

CREATE TABLE #DataNumers
(
    [number] INT
);

DECLARE @max_diff_in_months INT;

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([client_id], [adm_date], [disch_date], [diff_in_months])
SELECT [client_id]
      ,[adm_date]
      ,ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE()) AS [disch_date]
      ,CEILING(DATEDIFF(MONTH, [adm_date], ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE())) * 1.0 / 3.0) - 1
FROM @DataSource
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 3, [adm_date]) <= ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE());

SELECT @max_diff_in_months = MAX([diff_in_months])
FROM #DataSource;

INSERT INTO #DataNumers ([number])
SELECT TOP (@max_diff_in_months) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM [master]..[spt_values];

SELECT DS.[client_id]
      ,DS.[adm_date]
      ,DATEADD(MONTH, DN.[number] * 3, [adm_date]) AS [3Month Date]
      ,DS.[disch_date]
FROM #DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY #DataNumers DN
WHERE DS.[diff_in_months] >= DN.[number];
```

[image]

The algorithm is the following:

1. select only the rows we needed
2. calculate the differences in months/3 for each row
3. generate numbers in helper table
4. generate the new rows using `cross apply`

You can use `CROSS JOIN` if you have more then 2.5k numbers [to generate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994136/1080354) but  I remove it in my example. Also, we are using `[master]..[spt_values]` to generate the total periods. But it's just one way for generating numbers in T-SQL. You can check the link and use another technique if you like.

The idea is to find the periods between each `[adm_date]` and `[disch_date]` - and a period is measure by 3 months - that's why we are using  `DATEDIFF` with `MONTH` and then dividing by 3. We are using [ceiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the upper value. Of course, you can generate more periods than needed and exclude them with `WHERE` clause in the final result.

Comment: If you include, say, `(1, '20010101', '20050115')` as a row in the datasource, it skips the last row (it should include 20050101).

Comment: @seanb in the following row  ,CEILING(DATEDIFF(MONTH, [adm_date], ISNULL([disch_date], GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 3.0) -1   if you remove "-1" it works!

Comment: @gotqn   it worked perfectly!  Questions                                                                                       about ,CEILING(DATEDIFF(MONTH, [adm_date], ISNULL([disch_date], GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 3.0)   Could you explain it?    And - what is [master]..[spt_values]?  (I've found [[master].[dbo].spt_values in my DB)   Greates thanks, as usual!

Comment: @Hell-1931 I explain in the edit. Could to share what's the performance now?

Comment: @gotqn And it absolutely worked - I just had to replace INSERT INTO   values   to  INSERT INTO SELECT FROM  myDBTable
And - remove "-1" from CEILING(DATEDIFF(MONTH, [adm_date], ISNULL([disch_date], GETUTCDATE())) * 1.0 / 3.0) - 1  , so it would add up the 3M to the last row before dich-date > 3M date