# How do I get the last 12 months date of today?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

How can I get the last 12 months date as of today ?

Ex:

```
2020-10-21
2020-09-21
2020-08-21
2020-07-21
2020-06-21
2020-05-21
2020-04-21
2020-03-21
2020-02-21
2020-01-21
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', 
           DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())
```

But this gives me only last month.

Comment: If today was the 31st of the month what results would you expect?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate those rows, you can use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 0 n
    union all select n + 1 from cte where n < 12
)
select dateadd(month, -n, convert(date, getdate())) dt from cte order by dt
```

This gives you today's date, and the same day of the month for the preceding 12 month (so that's a total of 13 rows). You can adjust the inequality condition in `cte` to the the exact number of iterations that you want. If you need more than 100 iterations, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

Comment: Thank you so much GMB. it works like a charm. Cheers

Comment: Is there a way I can dynamically add month when it's next month ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive CTE, but these can have rather negative impact on performance sometimes. If you don't have a numbers table that would be useful here, you can use a system table to generate rows and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to give them numbers 1..12, like so:

```
select top 12 dateadd(month, 1-row_number() over (order by (select null)), getdate()) 
  from sys.all_objects
```

[Working example on dbfiddle.uk, both recursive and with the above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4cd747aec45b93f08ac3bdcf00b76bd)

Comment: This works but is there a way i can do it dynamically instead of manually like for ex: top 12 from this month shows last 12 months but if its this:

select top 10 dateadd(month, 1-row_number() over (order by (select null)), convert(date,getdate()+30)) Dates
 from sys.all_objects

Is there a way that I can get even the month of Jan 2020

Answer (score 1):

Using an inline tally seems simple enough here, in my opinion:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,V.[Date])
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,GETDATE())))V([Date])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(0),(-1),(-2),(-3),(-4),(-5),(-6),(-7),(-8),(-9),(-10),(-11))T(I);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [various ways](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) to generate a sequence of numbers between 1 and 12. Pick one. Once you have the sequence you just need to add DATEADD to it, e.g. like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DATEADD(MONTH, 0-Number, GETDATE())
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```